# MySQL select max record from each group and insert into another table

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

There are 4 columns in table A, id, name, create_time and content.

```
create table A
(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(20),
    create_time datetime,
    content varchar(4000)
);
create table B like A;
```

I want to select max `create_time` records in the same `name`, and insert into another table `B`.

Execute sql as follow, but the time consumption is unacceptable.

```
insert into B
select A.*
from A,
    (select name, max(create_time) create_time from B group by name) tmp
where A.name = tmp.name
  and A.create_time = tmp.create_time;
```

A table has 1000W rows and 10GB, execute sql spend 200s.

Is there any way to do this job faster, or change which parameters in MySQL Server to run faster.

p:
table A can be any type, paration table or some else.

Comment: Do you mean "select name, max(create_time) create_time from *A* ..." ?

Comment: You want all records in table B, or only one per name? In the first case, shouldn't you then name the max() something different than create_time to avoid collision with the already existing column in A? Or don't you want to keep the original create_time? In the second case (only one record per name), what should be the content and the id? Some sample data and expected result in your question would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First be sure you have proper index  on A (name, create_time) and B  (name, create_time)
then try using explicit join and on condtion

```
insert into B 
select A.* 
from A 
inner join ( 
    select name, max(create_time) create_time 
    from B 
    group by name) tmp on  ( A.name = tmp.name and A.create_time = tmp.create_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is:

```
INSERT INTO B
SELECT m.*
FROM A m                                      # m from "max"
LEFT JOIN A l                                 # l from "later"
    ON m.name = l.name                        # the same name
        AND m.create_time < l.create_time     # "l" was created later than "m"
WHERE l.name IS NULL                          # there is no "later"
```

#### How it works:

It joins `A` aliased as `m` (from *"max"*) against itself aliased as `l` (from *"later"* than *"max"*). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that, in the absence of a `WHERE` clause, all the rows from `m` are present in the result set. Each row from `m` is combined with all rows from `l` that have the same `name` (`m.name = l.name`) and are created  after the row from `m` (`m.create_time < l.create_time`). The `WHERE` condition keeps into the results set only the rows from `m` that do not have any match in `l` (there is no record with the same name and greater creation time).

#### Discussion

If there are more than one rows in `A` that have the same `name` and `creation_time`, the query returns all of them. In order to keep only one of them and additional condition is required.

Add:

```
OR (m.create_time = l.create_time AND m.id < l.id)
```

to the `ON` clause (right before `WHERE`). Adjust/replace the `m.id < l.id` part of the condition to suit your needs (this version favors the rows inserted earlier in the table).

**Make sure the table `A` has indexes on the columns used by the query (`name` and `create_time`).** Otherwise the performance improvement compared with your original query is not significant.

Comment: table A has indexes on name and create_time,your solution execution plan seems not much difference to me.how can I optimize this sql.

Comment: Have you ran it? How much time does it need to complete?