# MYSQL group by with last value but conditional

Tags: mysql

I'll explain my scenario. Mysql 5.7

I have 2 table: registry and movement.
This two table have **IDMovement** in common so i can join them

My problem:
I need to GROUP BY the **Registry** column (is varchar column), i need to check the MAX **IDMovement**. In this row, there is another column called **IDCausal**. If on the MAX **IDMovement** the **IDCasual** is different to 21, then skip. Else return the row.

I'll make an example of what i have done:

```
SELECT
    m.IDMovement,
    mo.IDCausal,
    m.Registry 
FROM
    registry m
    JOIN movement mo ON m.IDMovement = mo.IDMovement 
WHERE
    m.Registry = "2SST0160"
```

P.S. The WHERE is just an example, i need to do the query for every Registry.

The return values for the registry 2SST0160 are:

```
IDMovement   IDCausal  Registry
5550         21        2SST0160
9817         5         2SST0160
```

In the example, the MAX IDMovement is 9817 but the IDCausal is 5, so the expected result of the query in this case is a NOTHING. If the IDCausal was 21, the expected result is only the row with 21. For every Registry, i'll expect ZERO or ONE row as result for every registry.

I'll hope i was clear, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x so you can use window functions?

Comment: No. As i have say, is 5.7 unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, missed that you said that. Write a subquery that returns the row with MAX(IDMovement) for each `Registry`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1. Join with that and test if the max is 21.

Comment: I have see that discussion, but mine isn't a single table but already is a join, so I don't know how to manage

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145885/sql-selecting-from-two-tables-with-inner-join-and-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: _"If on the MAX IDMovement the IDCasual is different to 21, then skip. Else return the row."_ -- `GROUP BY` and the SQL aggregate functions do not select rows. `GROUP BY` creates new rows using the values from a group of rows. The value in each column is computed separated and the final created row does not exist in the input table(s). This is a common mistake and misunderstanding about `GROUP BY`. Your need can be fulfilled but not by using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Learn from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802817/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579929/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410533/4265352) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381339/4265352) on similar questions how to select the row that has the `MAX` value from its group on some column (without using `GROUP BY` because `GROUP BY` does a different thing).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH newtable AS ( SELECT
    m.IDMovement,
    mo.IDCausal,
    m.Registry
FROM
    registry m
    JOIN movement mo ON m.IDMovement = mo.IDMovement
WHERE
    m.Registry = '2SST0160' )
SELECT * FROM newtable
    WHERE (SELECT IDCausal FROM newtable ORDER BY IDMovement DESC LIMIT 1) = 21
    ORDER BY IDMovement DESC LIMIT 1;
```